# Why is the absolute sign needed in the definition of a bounded function

Tags: definition, absolute-value

A function $f$ is bounded if there exists a real number $M$ such that $|f(x)| \le M$ for all $x \in \operatorname{dom}(f)$. Why is the absolute sign needed?

Comment: Informally, imagine 'absolute value' as a [norm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Norm_(mathematics)#Absolute-value_norm) that tells you how 'big' something is.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Because if it's just "$f(x)\leq M$" then $f$ could "blow down" to $-\infty$.

Comment: Also, the definition $|f(x)|\leq M$ means the same definition can be used for complex-valued functions.

Answer (score 12):

Here is why:

Suppose we let $f(x) = \begin{cases} x & x < 0 \\ 0 & x \geq 0 \end{cases}$.

Should such a function be considered "bounded"?  It is certainly bounded from above (by $1$ for example), so $f(x) \leq 1$ is true for all $x$...but it isn't bounded from below.  $\lim \limits_{x \to - \infty} f(x) = - \infty$, which means our function is not bounded from below.

This is remedied by saying $|f(x)| \leq M$, because then by definition, $|f(x)| \leq M$ implies $-M \leq f(x) \leq M$, so that $f$ is bounded from above and below.

Answer (score 7):

If $M\geq0$ then $|y|\leq M$ is equivalent to $-M\leq y\leq M$, so the definition is just saying there is $M\geq0$ so that $-M\leq f(x)\leq M$ for all $x$. This is just a standard economy of notation; it might just as well have said there exist $M_1,M_2$ such that $M_1\leq f(x)\leq M_2$ for all $x$. On the other hand, if the values of $f$ are complex numbers, then saying $f(x)\leq M$ would not even make sense, and this this becomes more that just a shorthand (even though $|f(x)|\leq M$ is still equivalent to saying that the real and imaginary parts of $f(x)$ are bounded).

Answer (score 6):

A more general definition of bounded is that a (real) function $f(x)$ is bounded if there exist real numbers $m, M$ such that $m \le f(x) \le M $ for all $x$. Now there is no modulus involved and it shows that the upper and lower bounds need not be negations of each other.

It follows that if $f$ is bounded by this definition and $L = max( |m|, |M|)$ then $|f(x)| \le L$, and conversely that if $|f(x)| \le L$ then $-L \le f(x) \le L$.

Comment: Well, or that $f(\operatorname{def} f)$ is a bounded set? :)

Comment: The definition you posit is not more general, since it defines exactly the same class of real functions as being bounded -- you prove one direction; for the converse, if $|f(x)|<M$ for all $x$, then setting $m=−M$ shows the function is bounded in the sense you use.

Comment: I think it is more general in that it may contain more information, i.e. different lower and upper bounds, and in any case it's in that sense that I mean it. My second paragraph shows that the same functions are bounded according to both definitions.

Answer (score 3):

## Case 1:

$f$ is a $\mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ function:

#### The definition can have multiple equivalent forms:

$\exists\ m, M \in \mathbb{R} : \forall\ x \in dom(f) : m \leq f(x) \leq M$

$\exists\ M \in \mathbb{R} : \forall\ x \in dom(f) : - M \leq f(x) \leq M$

$\exists\ M \in \mathbb{R} : \forall\ x \in dom(f) : | f(x) | \leq M$

#### When teaching calculus it is usually done this way:

$f$ is upper bounded $\leftrightarrow \exists\ M \in \mathbb{R} : \forall\ x \in dom(f) : f(x) \leq M$

$f$ is lower bounded $\leftrightarrow \exists\ m \in \mathbb{R} : \forall\ x \in dom(f) : m \leq f(x)$

$f$ is (generally) bounded $\leftrightarrow$ $f$ is upper and lower bounded

## Case 2:

$f$ is a $\mathbb{C} \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ function:

Since complex numbers can not be compared the only option from the three definitions abowe is the third. That is also correct for real and complex and even more abstract functions if the $|.|$ is correctly defined. For example any euclidean space. So it also works for $\mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^m$ functions.

Note that $|.|$ can be defined in multiple ways. For example:

$\sqrt{(Im z) ^ 2 + (Re z) ^ 2}$

$|Im z| + |Re z|$

Comment: Not quite true that the absolute value is the only option for the complex or higher dimensional case. The analogy of the upper and lower bounds version is to do that component wise, essentially defining a bounding box rather than a disc/ sphere. Of course, for the complex case at least, the disc is often going to be a lot more convenient.

Comment: Thanks for the note. I corrected it the way I meant.

Answer (score 2):

I think the definition should be
\begin{equation}
|f(x)| \leq M.
\end{equation}
We need the absolute value so that $f$ is also bounded from below. For example, if we only had 
\begin{equation}
f(x) \leq M,
\end{equation}
$f$ can be unbounded below. That is, we can have $f$ approaching $-\infty$.

Comment: Yeah you're right, I fixed the definition now.

Answer (score 1):

An equivalent definition of bounded would be "$f$ is bounded if there exists an $M \ge 0$ such that $-M \le f(x) \le M$". But this requires $f$ to be a real function. On the other hand $|f(x)|$ is real by definition of the absolute value function $|.|$

Answer (score 1):

One interpretation of *bounded function* is that a function $f:X \to \mathbb R$ is bounded when its image $f(X)$ is bounded. Now, $Y\subseteq\mathbb R$ is bounded exactly when it is contained in an interval. For simplicity, we can take this interval as being symmetric around the origin: $Y\subseteq [-M,M]$. Applying this to $Y=f(X)$, we get $|f(x)|\le M$, for all $x\in X$.

Another interpretation is that a function $f:X \to \mathbb R$ is bounded  when the *magnitude* of its values is bounded. Magnitude in $\mathbb R$ is measured by the absolute value.

Comment: The second is a recursive definition. ;)